# Slide Out Using <div> Tag

Tags: jquery, html

First, I'm sorry if I ask very newbie question..

Please see the problem:

[image]

It's very much like this one: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/toggle/default.html

But how to place the button float on the left/right side of page.

Big thanks, sorry for bad English. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: just to clarify, are you asking what sort of CSS is used to get that button to stick there? Such as position:fixed?   Or are you asking more specifically how to do this in Blogger itself?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a floating menu.

I found a page that describes putting in on blogger.  I have not tried it myself.

http://haseebnet.blogspot.ca/2013/01/floating-menu-for-your-blogger-blog.html#.Uh7wcBsqZR0

Edit:
You might bee looking for a "collapsing" or "accordion" menu(two different things).
This guy made a collapsing one on his blogger:

http://markthomson.blogspot.ca/2008/07/collapsible-menu-in-blogger.html

Comment: I mean when we hover on the [Button], some content slide out, so it's not just floating.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to a working piece of code to practice.  Check this

**HTML:**

```
<button>button</button>
<div>Solve HTTP Error 503. The service is in IIS</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
button {
    width:1px;
    word-break: break-all;
    position: fixed;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50px;
    display: none;
    left: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
$('button').hover(function (e) {
    $('div').toggle("slide", 500);
});
```

Here is a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/59WSs/) similar to your expectation.

A small explanation:

1) To **vertically align the text** in button use this below CSS

```
width:1px;
word-break: break-all;
```

2) Use **`.hover()`** for hovering functionality that you want to do with **`.toggle()`**

```
 $('div').toggle("slide", 500);
```

There is no need of callback here.

Hope this is pretty enough for you to start your own.